# What Software does MikeSchinkel use to create his stunning screen shots and is it available for Windows?

Tags: discussion, formatting

### I'm sure everyone has seen answers similar to [this one](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/578/) by MikeSchinkel that contain stunning screen shots with drop shadows, nice clear bold text and non squiggly red circles.

[image]

### **My screenshots never come out that good and my red circles always end up squiggly.**

[image]

I use the [Windows 7 snipping tool](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Use-Snipping-Tool-to-capture-screen-shots) to create mine along with my Wacom Intuos 4 tablet and I would like to know what he uses to create his.

It is possibly one of those cool Mac features that let you do this.  Does anyone know if something like this is available for Windows?  I have Photoshop CS5 but it's too much trouble to open it up just to edit a screen shot.

Comment: Have you considered, you know, sending him an email and asking?  His contact information is very prominent on [his profile](http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/89/mikeschinkel).

Comment: The reason for the question was more intended to get others ideas on what they used and to give Mike some praise for putting in so much effort in his answers.  I though it might also inspire others.

Comment: Squiggly lines are better! :)

Comment: Look what happens when I have to walk away for a while!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Skitch

This is what convinced me to buy a Mac.  Mind you it's not been a completely happy transition (I doubt I will ever be a fanboy), but here I am.  At least [Skitch](http://www.skitch.com/) (and a few other bits of software) are awesome!

-Mike

Comment: I've been contemplating a move to Mac, but philosophically its about as opposite as one can get from what I use now: Linux

Comment: *@Ash G*: My advice?  Stick with Linux and then you won't be disappointed.

Answer (score 1):

[PicPick](http://www.picpick.org/) is currently **the** utility for screenshots on Windows. Multiple capture modes, multiple destinations, additional tools, image editor - it has it all. Free for non-commercial use.

For edits I mostly use [Paint.NET](http://www.getpaint.net/) (simply because I am used to it and it has plugin for optimized PNG output) or [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/) if I need to more complex text (easier to do in vector for me).

PS shameless plug - [screenshot tag](http://www.rarst.net/tag/screenshot/) at my blog, several posts both on tools and techniques.

Comment: Thanks!  I just installed it. I really like that it has tabs.  With Snip it you could only do one capture at a time.

Comment: @Chris_O myself I just set it up so captured images open in Paint.NET automatically by default, highly convenient

Answer (score 1):

O found another tool that is very helpful in researching answers and creating screen shots.

[Digo](http://www.diigo.com/index) is a [Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/oojbgadfejifecebmdnhhkbhdjaphole) that allows you to highlight text from any web page and create sticky notes that are saved to your library along with a cash of the page.  It works together with the [Awesome Screenshots](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/alelhddbbhepgpmgidjdcjakblofbmce) extension and stores your annotated screen shots with your highlights in your library.

[Diigo V5: Collect and Highlight, Then Remember!](http://vimeo.com/12687333) from [diigobuzz](http://vimeo.com/user2347997) on [Vimeo](http://vimeo.com).

Answer (score 0):

Cross Plattform (?), Firefox Add-On for Screenshots with annotations: [FireShot (Firefox Add-On)](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5648/) - At least this should work under windows. There are other Add-Ons for Firefox as well.