# What tools do you use to answer questions?

Tags: discussion, answers

If you have useful tools to help you when you are writing an answer on a WPSE question, please list them here so we can all benefit from them!

Answer (score 10):

I wrote a small script that creates a new plugin, based on the question ID. It uses [the Stack Exchange API](https://stackapps.com/) to get the question info, puts that in the plugin header, and opens the file in an editor.

I created a local setup with all WP versions since 1.5, with a plugin dir that has a symlink called `wpse` to a common plugin folder. I just need to go to this plugin folder, type `wpse/create 1234`, and it creates a plugin for question #1234 in the common folder, and a symlink in this version's plugin folder. If I want to try it out in another version I just create an extra symlink.

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
// This file is called `create`, in the common folder, and made executable
function createWPSEPlugin( $idQuestion )
{
    $questionInfo = getWPSEQuestionInfo( $idQuestion );

    if ( ! $questionInfo ) {
        exit( "Cannot get question info\n" );
    }

    $questionSlug = strtolower( preg_replace( '/[^\w\-]/', '', str_replace( ' ','-', $questionInfo->title ) ) );

    $pluginDir = $idQuestion . '-' . $questionSlug;

    $baseDir = dirname( __FILE__ );

    if ( is_dir( $baseDir . '/' . $pluginDir ) ) {
        exit( "Plugin already exists here!\n" );
    }

    if ( ! mkdir( $baseDir . '/' . $pluginDir ) ) {
        exit( "Cannot make plugin dir!\n" );
    }

    $pluginFilename = 'wpse-' . $idQuestion . '.php';

    $fh = fopen( $baseDir . '/' . $pluginDir . '/' . $pluginFilename, 'w' );

    if ( ! $fh ) {
        exit( "Cannot create plugin file!\n" );
    }

    fwrite( $fh, <<<EOF
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: WPSE {$idQuestion}
Plugin URI: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/{$idQuestion}/{$questionSlug}
Description: {$questionInfo->title}
Version: 1.0
Author: Jan Fabry
*/
EOF
    );

    fclose( $fh );

    $currentDir = getcwd();

    if ( 'plugins' == basename( $currentDir ) ) {
        // Educated guess: we are in a WP plugin dir
        symlink( $baseDir . '/' . $pluginDir, 'wpse-' . $idQuestion );
    }

    // Extra: open plugin file. Change this to suit your situation
    exec( 'open ' . $baseDir . '/' . $pluginDir . '/' . $pluginFilename );
}

function getWPSEQuestionInfo( $idQuestion )
{
    $urlAPI = 'http://api.wordpress.stackexchange.com/1.0/questions/';

    // This is probably not the best way to do this...
    $compressedResponse = file_get_contents( $urlAPI . $idQuestion );
    $jsonResponse = file_get_contents( 'compress.zlib://data://text/plain;base64,' . base64_encode( $compressedResponse ) );

    $arrayResponse = json_decode( $jsonResponse );

    return $arrayResponse->questions[0];
}

createWPSEPlugin( $argv[1] );
```

Comment: wow, very cool -- consider listing this on meta.so as well

Comment: @Jeff: As a WordPress-specific "question", or make it more generic, so people can post stub generators for other languages too?

Answer (score 8):

I modified Jan Fabry's plugin above and created a mini-app of sorts that spits out a plugin file based on the question ID.

Here's what the front-end form looks like:

[image]

Here's a sample of what is generated.

[image: WPSE Generated Plugin]

All you need to do is:

- Download the files here: https://github.com/inspectorfegter/WPSE-Plugin-Generator
- Dump the contents onto your local server
- Configure the plugin-generator.php defaults to insert your name and WPSE profile URL.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a simple workflow I use to identify answers to ***difficult questions*** that aren't obvious in the Codex or from previous experience: http://3-3.me/eMTF

Here's my local setup for researching/testing/etc...

- Standard local installation of WordPress setup to create and test answers
- I use my IDE's 'find in files' function to search WordPress core for functions, HTML class names, or any other clue I can find on the DOM to help locate functionality
- My IDE is also setup to track WP phpdocs and functions. This allows me to easily traverse the core by simple shift-clicks on the convenient links to the original functions.
- I use Twenty Eleven with no plugins activated for testing answers as it is a good sanity check against rogue code in custom themes/plugins.

As a caveat, if difficult questions pertain to specific plugins, I rarely answer them and usually direct users to the plugin author via the WordPress.org forums. I am also careful not to do the entire work for the user, but give them a functional proof-of-concept.

Answer (score 0):

We already had [a related question about creating screenshots](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176/what-software-does-mikeschinkel-use-to-create-his-stunning-screen-shots-and-is-it). [Skitch](http://www.skitch.com/) was recommended for Mac users.

Comment: **@Jan Fabry:** Yes, I would love to see more people providing screenshots with Skitch or another tool that provides shadows; they make for a much more pleasing view.